# Automaticly update component when item delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, react-query

**Problem**

I have code which deletes a component. It works, but when I click delete button, I need to reload browser to see it's deleted.

Is there a way to immediately show page without this element?
I tried a few things,  but nothing works form me. Is rerender the only soultion??? Maybe I should use state managment like redux.

```
 const CardWithEdit = ({
  width,
  height,
  bckImg,
  color,
  children,
  link,
  editLink,
  id,
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setState(!state);

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/albums/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
    
    handleClick();
  };

  return (
    <Card width={width} height={height} bckImg={bckImg}>
      <AlbumtTitle color={color}>{children}</AlbumtTitle>
      <LinkButton background={color} to={link}>
        See more
      </LinkButton>
      <IconWrapper>
        <div>
          <Link to={editLink}>
            <AiOutlineEdit />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
          <AiOutlineDelete
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </IconWrapper>
      {state && (
        <Dialog
          handleClick={handleClick}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          deleteText={"Delete"}
        />
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And Main component albums.js

```
import React from "react";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import CardWithEdit from "../components/Card/CardWithEdit";
import ErrorMessage from "../components/ErrorMessage";
import { CartWrapper } from "../components/Wrappers";
import { apiStates, useApi } from "../hooks/useApi";
const Albums = () => {
  const { state, error, data } = useApi("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/albums");

  const albums = data.data;
  switch (state) {
    case apiStates.ERROR:
      return <ErrorMessage>{error || "General error"}</ErrorMessage>;
    case apiStates.SUCCESS:
      return (
        <CartWrapper>
          {albums.length > 0 ? (
            albums.map((album) => (
              <CardWithEdit
                width={"23rem"}
                height="16rem"
                color={album.color}
                bckImg={album.bckImgUrl}
                key={album._id}
                link={`/albums/${album._id}`}
                editLink={`edit/${album._id}`}
                id={album._id}
              >
                {album.name}
              </CardWithEdit>
            ))
          ) : (
            <h1>No albums yet</h1>
          )}
        </CartWrapper>
      );
    default:
      return <Loader />;
  }
};

export default Albums;
```

Comment: I think your problem is not in these lines of code, some where you store a liast of album ? you should update the album list to make the array changes so you will see the item deleted.

Comment: Why is `handleDelete` `async` if you don't `await` anything? What/where is your source of truth that you are rendering your UI from? If you optimistically update that then your UI will nearly be "in synch" with the backend.

Comment: when you delete something then set your state and delete that object from your array so it will remove in realtime

Comment: @NishargShah its react-query lib

Comment: First of all do not reload your webpage everytime you delete something. It will download your whole website code again. Instead save your data in a state, and update the state, this will cause re-rendering, which is a better solution than reload

Re-rendering will show your changes in realtime and that too at lightning fast speed, so use re-rendering instead of reloading

Comment: But if you still want to reload, than after you have succesfully deleted something call:

window.location.href = "your url",

this will reload your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need something like redux for this.

To get around your problem, I would do the following:

In the Main Component, update the album constant to `const [albums, setAlbums] = useState(data.data)`;

Create a function in the Main Component:

```
const handleDelete = id => {
    setAlbums(albums => albums.filter(album => album._id != id));
}
```

- Note that as now albums is a state variable, creating a new array with filter will cause the component to re-render when handleDelete is called.

In your Card Component, accept a new prop called `onDelete`, and pass the new function `handleDelete` from your Main Component into it like so:

```
<CardWithEdit
    width={"23rem"}
    height="16rem"
    color={album.color}
    bckImg={album.bckImgUrl}
    key={album._id}
    link={`/albums/${album._id}`}
    editLink={`edit/${album._id}`}
    id={album._id}
    onDelete={handleDelete}
>
```

and:

```
const CardWithEdit = ({
    width,
    height,
    bckImg,
    color,
    children,
    link,
    editLink,
    id,
    onDelete,
    }) => {
```

In the handleDelete function of your Card Component, after doing the DELETE request, simply call `onDelete(id)`

And just like that, you should have the functionality that you're requesting. Let me know if there are any issues!